# Book about someone trecking across Russia to get to America during a dystopian ice age

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

Looking for a book my mother read years ago.

All she remembers is that someone was trying to cross an ice bridge from Russia (home) to America during a dystopian ice age, but first they had to cross Siberia and there were some nasty people living there.
My mother probably read the book sometime in the 1970-1990, whether it was a full length novel or a short story is anyones guess...

Comment: Does your mother know how many years ago she read it? Was it new at the time? What media was it, novel, novella, short story, etc.? You can [edit] these details in.

Comment: Sounds like "Babylon A.D." movie and "Babylon Babies" book (by Maurice Dantec). 1999 for book, though.